# Assigning to a pointer returned by a function call

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, variable-assignment

I'm trying to implement a simple LinkedList
The following code, producing this error:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

The line is:

```
newNode->getNext() = _head;
```

Where `getNext()` returns a `Node*`, and i'm trying to make the new `Node` point at the current head before updating it.
I'm probably thinking in Java and doing the transition wrong.

Comment: without your implementation it's only guessing...

Comment: Refrain from using leading underscores for variable names, as they are reserved for compiler usage.  You may stomp on something and only spend a week debugging before finding out.  Early prevention: choose a different naming convention, such as underscores as suffixes.

Comment: @Thomas: Only when it's in the global namespace, or when the underscore is followed by a capital letter or another underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either, dereference:

```
Node* Node::getNext();
*(newNode->getNext()) = _head;
```

(assuming `_head` has type `Node` and the assignment operator was implemented with care in `Node`) or, what is probably better

```
Node& Node::getNext();
newNode->getNext() = _head;
```

But anyway, this is not the way you *should* be doing this. You may want to implement a setter.

Also, have you considered using `std::list` instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: I've chose the second.
_next is of type Node*, so i had to return *_next for this to work.
But i dont understand why it needs to be so.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're implementing the class, you have several options:

1. implement a `setNext(Node*)` method (possibly `private`) and use `newNode.setNext(_head)`;
2. assign to the node's `_next` member directly: `newNode._next = _head`;
3. make Node's constructors take the initial value of `_next` as an argument and pass `_head` when constructing `newNode`.

Since you didn't post your code, I took a guess at the name of the "next" pointer and called it `_next`. Also, the points 1-3 above are not mutually exclusive and are not the only possibilities.

P.S. Take a look at the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/misc/lvalue.html) if you're unsure what "lvalue" and "rvalue" mean.

Answer (score 0):

You're placing a function call on the left side, which you really can't do.  Are you sure you didn't mean...

```
_head = newNode->getNext();
```

Comment: or newNode->setNext(_head);  (not sure if this is valid, but you get the idea)

Comment: Assuming such a function exists, yes.

Comment: Re: "You're setting the return value of a function to _head,  which you really can't do."  There is no reason to conclude that this can't be done here.

Comment: @John So..you're saying that having a function on the left is perfectly legal? Regardless of what you're saying, reworded the answer to be more clear.

Comment: @MGZero: It's allowed as long as the result of the function call expression is an `lvalue` (rather than an `rvalue`). About the only time that this occurs is when the function returns a reference. (`[n3290: 3.10/1]:` "[..] As another example, the result of calling a function whose return type is an lvalue reference is an lvalue. [..]")

Comment: @Tomalak Ahh I see.  Never actually tried that with a reference.

Comment: @John: Nice doing business with you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the variable you are assigning to on the left hand side of the '=' sign.

`_head = newNode->getNext();`

After reading again, it doesn't really achieve what you want.  I'd recommend implementing a "setNext" function that takes a node as an arguement, or just accessing the 'next' variable directly. newNode.next = _head; for example.